# Get value from Button group php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tow button organized into button group and I wish to get selected value from this button group by php 
I send value from form.php to value.php using ajax 
this is the code of button group

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle" name="btn-group" id="btn-group"> 
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-Primary<?php if($row['self_reg']=="ON") echo " active"?>" value="ON">ON</button>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default <?php if($row['self_reg']=="OFF") echo "active"?>" value="OFF">OFF</button>
</div>
```

and this is the ajax code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadimage").on('submit', (function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "Save.php?id=self_register", // Url to which the request is send
                type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs  (i.e. form fields and values)
                contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the  server.
                cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file  it is set to false
                success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                {
                    //$('#loading').hide();
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
        }));
    });
</script>
```

I get value from ajax using php code

```
$button-group=$_POST['btn-group']
```

but unfortunately, it not worked

Comment: you may want to read basics of HTML forms. BTW: What value you expect you `btn-group` to have and why any at all?

Comment: `btn-group` is the name of the `<div>` so how can you get a value of div at server side ??

Comment: I want to get the value that user selected if he pressed off the value will be OFF and if he pressed on  the returned value is ON

Comment: I get the value by javascript using this code                                                      var myVar = $(".btn-group").find(".active").text();  and every thing go fine now I want get value by php

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to do it:

Page:

```
<form action="sohandler.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-Primary<?php if($row[ 'self_reg' ]=='ON') echo " active ";?>" name="btn" value="ON"></input>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default <?php if($row[ 'self_reg' ]=='OFF') echo " active ";?>" name="btn" value="OFF"></input>
</form>
```

Handler:

```
<?php
$btn = $_POST[ 'btn' ]; /* Note that you can NOT use "-" in variables */
echo $btn;
?>
```